# Finding the last blank in a string (simple stuff for you not me)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did this project yesterday for my class and today I am trying to recreate it to gain a better understanding but unfortunately I am caught up on one part.

I have to find the position of the last blank or ' ' in a user phrase using rfind().

I then have to slice the string into two parts:

- The first part containing all the words except the last (hence why I
  have to find the last blank or space)
- The second part containing the last word.

There is more to it but
          the first part, the finding the blank part is what I am really
          caught up on.

I am currently scripting using Python 3.8

I appreciate any help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have string:

```
string = 'abc def 123'
```

If you really want to do this with rfind, let's get last space with: `idx = string.rfind(' ')`

then you slice string into two:

```
first_string = string[:idx]
second_string = string[idx+1:] # you want to remove blank space, that's why you add +1 to idx
```

Comment: WOW i was using the rfind wrong :( Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to find the last blank. 
Split the string with blanks then join them excluding the last one.

```
stri=" Hello my name is gaurav "
str=stri.strip().split(' ')
str_first=' '.join(str[:-1])
str_last=str[-1]
print((str_first,str_last))
#prints ('Hello my name is', 'gaurav')
```

that `.strip()` is used incase there is blank after the last word and you get empty last word.

Comment: Thank you so much for this I am going to analyze this! Part of the assignment was for us to find the last blank using rfind.. Thats why It "has" to be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
yourString.rfind(' ')
```

you will automatically find the position of the last blank space.

But you don't actually need it to separate the sentence in two parts. Just use split:

```
firstPart, lastWord = (' '.join(yourString.split()[:-1]), yourString.split()[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you!! Part of the assignment was to split the string into two, and then reconnect them in the end

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

[`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) has an extra parameter which is how many time a string can be split. Setting it to 1 makes it split only once:

```
>>> 'This is my answer'.rsplit(' ', 1)
['This is my', 'answer']
```

If you **must** stick with [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind), you can cut the string after finding:

```
>>> s = 'This is my answer'
>>> lastpos = s.rfind(' ')
>>> s[:lastpos]
'This is my'
>>> s[lastpos + 1:]
'answer'
```

Note that you must check `if lastpos >= 0`, as getting a return value of `-1` (not found) would lead to wrong results.